# Get last row cell value from column N and if match specific word send email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am unable to get this script to check the whole column and get the last row cell value to compare.  It only works if I input a single cell that matches.

Tried this script and have tried many variations I have found on stackoverflow and none work for me.

```
function CNIC(){
  CheckCnic();
}

function CheckCnic() {
  // Fetch the Assigned Team
  var getassignedto = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Man Ticketing Log"); 
  var range = getassignedto.getRange('N:N');
  var lastRow = getassignedto.getLastRow();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var department = range.getValue();
  //var department = lastRow.getValue(); // This is the return value 
    of CNIC to match

  // Check if matches CNIC
  if (department == "CNIC"){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailAddress = ("myemail@mydomain.com");

    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'ATTENTION ' + department; // Second column
    var subject = 'A NEW TICKET HAS BEEN ADDED';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It only gets a single cell because that's exactly what you're asking it to do.

`var values = range.getValues();
var department = range.getValue();`

`getValue()` returns a single cell's value. If you want to check multiple rows in a column, either loop through `values`, or use a [`TextFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: So i updated both lines with the getValues and nothing has changed.  Am i missing somethine more ?

Comment: Again, if you want to check through multiple values, use a loop.